# Why time taken to charge the laptop battery increases rapidly when it almost full?

Tags: 12.04, laptop, battery, acpi

When my laptop is charging at first it charges normally. But when its charged about 98% time remaining begins to increase why is this?
[image]

Comment: "Time to full" is simply based on the time it needs to go to 100% based on the *current* energy rate. However, that rate is far from constant. A battery nearly full will charge slower so the energy rate drops, increasing the estimate. This behaviour has nothing to do with Ubuntu - it's the power controller in your notebook doing this.

Comment: It is not a fault in the battery so?

Comment: No, this is how all rechargeable batteries work. Charging rate drops as soon as you come close to the maximum capacity. See also the charge current in the graph on this page: http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries

Comment: Thanks. Im new to this laptop stuff and I was bit afraid whether it has some thing to do with the battery,

Comment: Ubuntu would provide you a better estimate if it would account for the change in current. However, this is very laptop specific and it may be implemented some day. I've seen power profiles being generated by Gnome Power daemon based on measurements taken in the background while using the machine, but it seems unused for the calculations. I'm sure someone reported this already somewhere on a bug tracker - go out and find it or report it yourself. ;)